# Zend 1.12 Controller Url helper adding extra string

Tags: url, zend-framework, controller

I'm trying to add an extra string to the url using $this->_helper->url so I'm on the page:

```
/books/adventure
```

bookes is a controller and adventure is an action. Now in the adventure method I'd like to generate urls like:

```
/books/adventure/id/4/my-book-title
```

I know how to add id parameter but how can I add book-title string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url` provides only key/value generation posibility. You could build your own url action helper on top of it. Just extend the `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url`.

or you could modify the url string in view by output.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it easilly with `Zend_Routes`

Here the Zend Framework Reference for Routes [Zend Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/fr/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex)